# Browser is closed only if test passed

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, c#

I used `driver.Quit();` in TeardownTest method.
But the browser is closed only if the test passed.
If a test failed, the browser is still open.
Why browser is not closed in this case?

We have Microsoft Visual team services builds, Visual Studio Test Agent is deployed to virtual machine. On the virtual machine is installed MS Agent for Visual studio 2015 Update 3. This problem, with closing the browser, happens only on virtual machine. If I run tests from Visual Studio on local machine, browser is closed if test passed or failed, in this case it works.

Comment: Edit your question what you have tried. Add your code and error which shows your eclipse after running the code.

Comment: For example, if some element is not found, a test failed and the browser remains open. But if all steps of test methods are OK, a test passed and the browser is closed.

Comment: I am guessing you are not handling exceptions properly?

Comment: No exception or error regarding to close of browser is displayed. Only some exception regarding to find some element on the page is displayed, but it is not related to closing of browser.

Comment: How are you firing your tests? If you are using Test Explorer in Visual Studio, check to ensure you are not running your tests in *debug* mode. Also, can you tell us what test runner you are using? MSTest, NUnit, etc.

Comment: Also the code for your setUp and tearDown would be great to answer this question.

Comment: Likely your code is throwing an exception, and thus the program stops running.  The general workaround for this is to either catch the exception (try/finally type structures), or if you're using a test framework, there are generally setup and teardown methods to run things, regardless of whether tests succeed or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you are catching any exceptions, call driver.quit() within those catch blocks to close the browser when a test fails.  If there is a common point that all failing tests run through, I would put driver.quit() there instead of every catch block(ie. a reporting or logging method).

Answer (score 0):

We too faced the similar issue and a quick search on internet lead me here.

Then I examined the detailed log and found out that a report saving activity was throwing an exception in the `[TearDown]` and hence the `driver.Quit();` statement wasn't invoked.

It was referring a folder which wasn't there in the build system where as it is there in development environment!

So as a few people mentioned above, the issue is the exception but it seems it could come in different ways!

I wonder is it a good practice to save the report in `TearDown` action!

Answer (score -1):

```
 [TearDown]
        public void RunAfterEveryTest()
        {

            driver.Quit();
        }
```

Seems to be you are using NUnit, So please check the code you have for the trardown is same as the above code.

Or please share the code ..

Comment: jUnit? The question is tagged with C# think you are mistaken. Maybe NUnit or MStest, but certainly not jUnit :)

Comment: Yeah should be Nunit,Becouse the word "TearDown" is directly connecting with Junit, MStest it has only "TestCleanup". i edit my answer .